# MySQL: Use substring to derive data from two different columns

Tags: mysql, substring

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `vendor_contacts` (
  `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name_initials` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vendor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `vendor_contacts`
    VALUES (5,'Davison','Michelle',''),
           (12,'Mayteh','Kendall',''),
           (17,'Onandonga','Bruce',''),
           (44,'Antavius','Anthony',''),
           (76,'Bradlee','Danny',''),
           (94,'Suscipe','Reynaldo',''),
           (101,'O\'Sullivan','Geraldine',''),
           (123,'Bucket','Charles','');
```

I would like to run a query that extracts the first letter from the first name and last name columns.

```
SELECT vendor_id, last_name, first_name,  substring(first_name, 1, 1) AS initials
FROM vendor_contacts;
```

The following guide http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php, only shows how to work with one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pull them separately and combine them using `concat()`:

```
SELECT vendor_id, last_name, first_name,
       CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1)) as initials
FROM vendor_contacts;
```